# Micronaut not picking up config value through @Value annotation

Tags: java, dependency-injection, javabeans, micronaut

My application yaml is like so:

```
my:
  config:
    currentValue: 500
```

And my code tries to use this value like so:

```
@Singleton
public class MyClass {

  @Value("${my.config.current-value}")
  private final int myProperty;

  public MyClass(int myProperty) {
    this.myProperty = myProperty;
  }
}
```

But it isn't picking it up, because when I run the application I get an error:

```
{"message":"Internal Server Error: Failed to inject value for parameter [myProperty] of class: com.foo.bar.MyClass Message: No bean of type [java.lang.String] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you want both `@Value` on the field, but also want to assign the field a value in the constructor?

Comment: I don't! I was doing this all wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use constructor injection, you need to put the annotation onto the constructor parameter.

```java
@Singleton
public class MyClass {
 
  private final int myProperty;

  public MyClass(@Value("${my.config.current-value}") int myProperty) {
    this.myProperty = myProperty;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once I removed the attribute from the constructor, it works:

```
@Singleton
public class MyClass {

  @Value("${my.config.current-value}")
  private int myProperty;
  
}
```

Comment: "One cannot use a config value and inject it at the same time." - That is not true.  You can annotate the constructor parameter or you can annotate the field.  Both of those will use a config value that will be injected.

Comment: I see, thanks I'll update the answer. I'm still learning Micronaut.

Comment: No worries.  I am glad you figured it out.  Just as an FYI... when you inject directly into a private field like that, Micronaut has to use runtime reflection to access the field.  If you annotate a constructor parameter, or a non-private setter, or a non-private field, then runtime reflection is not required.  In general, avoiding runtime reflection is desired.